# Nested filter not working correctly in elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I cant make nested_filter sort work correctly.
I have such mapping -

```
"metadata": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true,
      "properties": {
        "property": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed",
          "include_in_parent" : false,
          "include_in_all" : false
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "lower_case_sort": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

So each file has metadata with property 'duration' and value has duration value for example 50.300.
Here I have the query that I am making but it is not returning the results either ascending or descending, it's random.

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
          "term" : {
                "parent.raw": "folderName"
           }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": {
        "metadata.value": {
            "order":"desc",
            "nested_filter": {
                "term": { "metadata.property":"duration" }
            }
        }
    }
}

What could be the issue?

Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0):

> The [nested_path and nested_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/sort-search-results.html#nested-sorting) options have been deprecated in
> favor of the options documented above 6.1.

Try out this below search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "parent.raw": "folderName"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "metadata.value": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "metadata",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "metadata.property": "duration"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is version 1.7, so with this I got - 
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[sort option [nested] not supported]

Comment: Yeah, so it looks like the issue lies in the mapping where the metadata.value.type is string instead of number/integer. Any chance I can parse that string to number when it contains number in ES script or something?